# Exception: Version mismatch:cffi

Tags: python, ubuntu, scrapy, pip, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to install scrapy using

```
pip install Scrapy
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
    Exception: Version mismatch: this is the 'cffi' package version 1.10.0, located in '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cffi/api.pyc'.
    When we import the top-level '_cffi_backend' extension module, we get version 1.5.2, located in '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_cffi_backend.x86_64-linux-gnu.so'.  
    The two versions should be equal; check your installation.
```

Tried installing the dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python-dev
```

Still the same error.

can anyone tell me what I'm missing ?

I'm on ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Have you tried upgrading `python-cffi` package via apt?

Comment: Yes, allready did that. Have I encountered a bug  ?

Comment: I removed all the cffi packages separately and installed version 1.5.2. Now it installed correctly. `sudo pip install cffi==1.5.2`

Answer (score 14):

I have just encountered a similar mistake. I solved this problem by referring to this [link](https://github.com/pogodevorg/pgoapi/issues/46).
The problem is that there are two different versions of 'cffi'.You can make sure the version is consistent by updating the old version.

You can try `sudo apt-get install python-cffi`.

Hope it can help you.

Comment: Tried it before. Encountered same issue again.

Comment: Your solution solved my problem while installing graphite-api on a raspberry pi.

Comment: `pip3 uninstall cffi` and then installing the Ubuntu/debian package with Synaptic, seems to solve it thanks.

Comment: E: Unable to locate package python-cffi

Comment: `sudo apt-get install python3-cffi`

Answer (score 4):

Install required version of cffi:

```
sudo pip3 install cffi==1.5.2
```

Better if you remove first